# Installing Arch Linux on an SSD

Tags: arch-linux, loop-device

I'm making my way through this:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide

I've done this successfully a couple of times when working with conventional HDDs but I've recently bought and installed the following SSD:

http://uk.transcend-info.com/Products/No-418 (32GB version)

I've reached the "preparing storage devices" section and the output from my

```
lsblk
```

command is the following:

```
NAME             MAJ:MIN  RM.  SIZE    RO  TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda              8:0      1    58.6G   0   disk
--sda1           8:1      1    58.6G   0   part  /run/archiso/boottmnt
sr0              11:0     1    1024M   0   rom
loop0            7:0      0    252.5M  1   loop  /run/archiso/sfs/airootfs
loop1            7:1      0    32G     1   loop
--arch_airootfs  254:0    0    32G     0   dm    /
loop2            7:2      0    256M    0   loop
--arch_airootfs  254:0    0    32G     0   dm    /
```

I'm booting the arch Linux installation from a 64GB USB stick, hence the first 2 entries.

My question is regarding the 'loop' devices.

Does this output look sensible? I was expecting to see the SSD appear as a single 'sda' device so I'm unsure where to go next. Can I install Arch on one of these loop devices and if so, which one? I assume loop1 but I'd like some sound advice before I continue. Also why are these loop devices all separate? Can anybody shed some concise light on this please?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is regarding the 'loop' devices.

What you are looking at with `lsblk` is the complicated mount structure of a **running linux live system**.

```
loop0            7:0      0    252.5M  1   loop  /run/archiso/sfs/airootfs
```

A loop device is only a *virtual* device - it's main idea is to turn a single big (compressed) file into a filesystem. It should maybe be called "deloop" device.

Above line shows how linux from and on the USB drive has mounted a loop device on point `airootfs`, under `/run`, which in turn is a virtual device based on RAM.

`findmnt` is the utility to get an overview.

The terminology is often unclear. Best consult wikipedia for the concepts. Quick washup:

**ssd, hdd**: products, not linux "devices". mass storage **internal and external**. Check dmesg at boot to see how the kernel approaches them. One speaks of "external HDD", or "USB SSD" (meaning external also!): giving info and avoiding the ambiguous term "device".

**sda, sdb**: recognized and alphabetically numbered **disks**. Anything more complex than floppy disk needs *partitioning*:

**sda1, sda2**: partititions, or block devices to be formatted with a filesystem. Only then your SSD can begin to store *files* (not just bytes)

Just for illustration: with RAID e.g. you add an extra "volume" level, for added functionality.

And the "famous" `dd` utility can write to both: disks and partitions. Both are "block devicey" enough.

Careful when you use it! you "only" need it to make a bootable USB drive (or disk)(or stick or pen drive...), and then you have to get that numbering letter "a", "b", "c", ... correct:

```
dd ... of=/dev/sda  #  This can "wipe" a whole internal disk.
dd ... of=/dev/sdb  #  oops. THIS is the external USB drive attached 

dd ... of=/dev/sda1  # first partition on first disk e.g. rootfs
dd ... of=/dev/sda7  # number seven, could be swap partition
```

`fdisk -l` gives a good list of partitions with their sizes and types per disk. Dont start fdisk interactively just to get that info.

Yes, without that background you will have a hard time installing linux. As I say: the words "ssd" and "device" are often used imprecisely. Now you know better!

The basic concept behind all this is concentrated in the `mount` command. That is what you want to be able to do, at startup, as sysadmin and as user:

```
mkdir data-f    # create mountpoint (first time only)
mount /dev/sdf35 data-f
```

The contents of that sata disk "sdf", partition #35, are now accessible as files: `cd data-f; ls; ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use `losetup` to check what each loop device refers to. Real disks should show up as one of `sd[a-z]`, `hd[a-z]`, `vd[a-z]`, ... or if it's a card reader, maybe `mmcblk[0-9]`...

Also, `smartctl -a $device` or `hdparm -i $device` should list name and type of the disk so you can verify you have the corerect one.

Example for my Crucial M4 64GB:

```
# hdparm -i /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

 Model=M4-CT064M4SSD2, FwRev=070H, SerialNo=0000000011290314D973
```

If the disk does not show up at all, check connectors/cables, try another enclosure, etc. or it may just be incompatible or dead on arrival.

As for the installation procedure, there should not be any difference between HDD / SSD, maybe save for alignment / discard.